# Sql Query For my case

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.5

I Have table in format mentioned below

```
USER_ID ORDER

1        0
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        0
2        1
2        3
3        0
3        2
```

I want to find list of user id whose ordering is not continious.
i.e userid2(have no ordering of 2)
and userid3(having no ordering of 1).

Please help

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Problem is i dnt understand the logic for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there can't be any duplicate `order` values for a `user_id`, this should work:

```
SELECT user_id, max(`order`)-min(`order`)+1 order_range_size, count(*) c
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING c != order_range_size
```

This doesn't tell you which `order` is missing from the range; I hope that's OK.